# text to csv search function javascript

Tags: javascript, search, text

i need write a function some_name(text, key_name) that parses text in
the CSV format( not required to handle quoting and escaping in values;
assume field values never contain commas or other special characters). Function must return a function that looks up a record by a value of the field
specified as the second argument to compile_csv_search. Assume that all values
in the key field are unique.

Sample usage:

```
var func_search = some_name(
    "ip,name,desc\n"+
    "10.49.1.4,server1,Main Server\n"+
    "10.52.5.1,server2,Backup Server\n",
    "name");

console.log(func_search("server2"));
console.log(func_search("server9"));
```

...will print:

```
{ip: "10.52.5.1", name: "server2", desc: "Backup Server"}
```

I split text in lines(\n), then split first line(,) and made array of keys for my result object that I return. But i don't understand what to do next. I must use closures, but I don't know how. I will be glad every help or tips that will be lead to solving this task.
This what i have:

```
function compile_csv_search (text, key_name) {
    var result={};
    var lines=text.split("\n");
    var key_names=lines[0].split(",");
    lines.shift();
    return function search (name) {  //"server2" in example
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
        /*
          some code
        */
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry for my engrish.

Answer (score 0):

For example.. http://jsfiddle.net/fvosqjvn/

```
var objs = {
    'data': [],
    'parseArray': function (ar)
    {
      var properties = ar[0].split(',');
      for (var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
      {
        var obj = {}, vals = ar[i].split(',');
        for(var j = 0; j < vals.length; j++)
           obj[properties[j]] = vals[j];  
        this.data.push(obj);
      }
    },
    'searchByProperty': function (property, search)
    { 
      return this.data.filter(function(el) {
          return el.hasOwnProperty(property) && el[property] == search;
      });
    }
}

var strs = "\
ip,name,desc\n\
10.49.1.4,server1,Main Server\n\
10.52.5.1,server2,Backup Server".split("\n");

objs.parseArray(strs);
console.log(objs.searchByProperty('name', 'server2'))
```

Comment: @user3342929 because it makes output through `console.log`